# Samba 4x netlogon scripts not executing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, domain, samba4, netlogon

I am in the process of migrating a domain configuration to another server, I am able to connect to the domain, and log in, plus get my X: drive, which is just the users home drive. The previous machine was set up by someone else, but I have found that the domain makes use of log in scripts. I've found these scripts and edited them on the new server to reflect naming changes.

When I log in to the domain on a client pc, I do not get the shares mapped that I would expect.

my smb.conf looks like this

```
[global]
idmap gid = 15000-20000
obey pam restrictions = yes
admin users = @admins, fstetson, jeff, mdecota
time server = yes
idmap uid = 15000-20000
logon script = default.cmd


[netlogon]
comment = Network Logon Service
path = /etc/samba/netlogon/%g
guest ok = Yes
browseable = No
```

my log on script default.cmd looks like:
net use h:\avalanche\alpah5

basically it's supposed to map that drive, but it doesn't.
I'm pretty new to domain work, on the old server these scripts seem to execute fine.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

For me, the syntax is wrong. I use for this aim, an UNC path '\computername\sharename\'

You can extend path with subfolders following path.

'net use /?' on Windows client machine should outline this, if I'm right it must have a space before UNC folder path.